# Multiple styles within same paragraph

Tags: html, css, fonts, formatting, font-size

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to style a paragraph in multiple ways such that the formatting is responsive and the text of different styles remains on the same line. I am a beginner, and have searched for other answers but can't figure it out, so please forgive me if the answer is quite obvious.

For example: I HATE hot dogs!

"I" would need to be 16px, "HATE" would need to be 40px, and "hot dogs!" would need to be 16px again, but I want all of the text within the same `<p>` if possible, or if not possible, at least to LOOK as if they're all in the same `<p>`. (The actual text I'm using is rather a long paragraph that needs to respond to different browser widths, so it's important for the text to be able to act as if it's one paragraph.)

I've jerry-rigged an extremely messy and only semi-successful solution using divs but I feel sure there should be a more elegant answer:

```css
.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 22px;
}

.container3 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.container4 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">I</div>
  <div class="container3">HATE
    <div class="container4">hot dogs!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why use block level elements instead of inline elements? Why mis-use float instead of using flexbox (would not be needed if you use inline-elements in the first place? IMHO the correct tag to use would be `<span>`

Answer (score 3):

As some people already said, you don't use `<div>` for this type of situation, instead, you need `<span></span>` which will allow different styles inside the same `<p>`. You can use CSS to define specific text styles:

**CSS Classes defining font size**

```css
.textA {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.textB {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="textA">I</span>
  <span class="textB">HATE</span>
  <span class="textA">hot dogs!</span>
</p>
```

**Inline Style**
This approach may seem shorter but it won't be as nice when styling a whole paragraph.

**Edit (note by @tacoshy):** should also never been used outside of email-templates. This will cause major specificty weight issues, cause low readbility and cant be cached which causes longer loading times.

```html
<p>
  <span style="font-size: 16px;">I</span>
  <span style="font-size: 40px;">HATE</span>
  <span style="font-size: 16px;">hot dogs!</span>
</p>
```

Remember you can also set other styles as font color, italic, bold, background color, etc.

Comment: inline-style should also never been used outside of email-templates. This will cause major specificty weight issues, cause low readbility and cant be cached which causes longer loading times.

Comment: thank you for help figuring out the different ways to do this - I really appreciate it as a self-taught beginner!

Comment: @tacoshy You're absolutely right! But I think it's also important to know every alternative way to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you would not use `<div>`. You would use the `<span>` element. It's meant for applying different styles to the same paragraph. Here the example from the one you gave in the question:

```css
p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.i {
  padding-top: 22px;
}

.hate {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.hd {
  padding-left: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class='i'>I</span>
  <span class="hate">HATE</span>
  <span class="hd">hot dogs!</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Oh, incredible! I'm going to try this out and see how it goes - as a basically ultra-beginner, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

One thing no one has noted is that you can (and should, IMO) use native, semantic HTML elements where possible, falling back to generic HTML elements where those fail.

There's no need for more than two elements; the containing paragraph, and the emphasized HATE word. Note I've defined the 16px font at the root level (`html`) and defined the 40px in relative terms to that (`2.5rem`). That way if a user changed their font sizes, the HATE would still be relatively large.

```css
html { font-size: 16px; }
em { font-size: 2.5rem; font-style: normal; }
```

```html
<p>I <em>HATE</em> hot dogs!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline-elements such as a `<span>`. You can either add classes to them or just use the `:nth-child` selector instead. Using float here is completely wrong. Also no reason for `position: absolut` or `relative`

```css
p :nth-child(1) {
  padding-top: 22px;
}

p :nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 40px;
}

p :nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>HATE</span>
  <span>hot dogs!</span>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks so much! this was really helpful - I am still a beginner and will experiment but I especially appreciate the flexibility and responsiveness of this solution, though it took me a bit to work through it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `span`. So...

HTML

```
<div class="container1">
   <p>I
      <span class="text-effect-1">HATE</span>
      <span class="text-effect-2">HOT DOGS</span>
   </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container1 p{
  font-size: ---;
  font-weight: ---;
  color: ---;
}

.text-effect-1{
  font-size: ---;
  font-weight: ---;
  color: ----;
}

.text-effect-2{
  font-size: ---;
  font-weight: ---;
  color: ----;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about span - and absolute and relative were left over from previous experimenting with containers. I appreciate this a lot!

Comment: Please post a working [repro] then you would also realize that your code does not work as intended. Your CSS selectors are completely wrong. The element `.container1` has no paragraph child element. The spans also have no child elements with the classes you declared.

Comment: Corrected a couple of things but the OP wanted a solution inside P tags. Container1 does have a P tag in my solution.

Comment: revoked the downvote after the fix. a repro should still eb used. Last but not least you should never ask for upvotes or your answer to be checked. Its against the guidelines.

Comment: Noted, thanks @Tacoshy for the advice.